# Reasons not to use iframes?

Tags: html, iframe

I've heard a lot of times that it's a bad idea to use iframes. But I never knew why. Is it really a bad idea? Could someone list a number of resons not to use them?

Supposing I wanted to use an iframe to load some content asynchronously to load my site faster, if this content wasn't meant to be indexed by search engines. Is it still bad idea to use an iframe?

Comment: Is not bad idea - you can used it when you needed. All tools/Technologies have the good the bad and the difficult side of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

["They are 1-2 orders of magnitude more expensive to create than any other type of DOM element, including scripts and styles"](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/06/03/using-iframes-sparingly/)

[image]

Comment: And is this a reason not to use them? If you need an iframe, use an iframe.

Comment: This is a reason to use them sparingly, as per the linked article.

Comment: I understand. Maybe I can't express my view correctly. If one is using iframes for stuff they were not meant to be used, they are misusing it. If an iframe is best suited for the job, it should be used, does not matter what kind of minor "performance hits" can occur. I'm saying this because there are thousands of "devs" around who would say "No, you should not use iframes, they are evil!!!44" because they heard things like this and cannot understand the big picture. Iframes have their place in web development.

Comment: You're entirely correct. You only need consider the above if there are multiple approaches available for what you're trying to achieve. You shouldn't just rule out iframes, as you said they have their place.